# Did my companion steal my gold?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I gave my money to my companion (around 5000 gold).

A few in game hours later I tried to get it back but my companion only had 500 gold on him.

What does that mean? Where's my gold?

Edit: the purpose of giving gold to my mate is because I give him all the misc items to keep my inventory organized.

Comment: It seems to be a reproductible bug. Giving him more than 500 gold and passing a door (ie. loading a new area) lowers the amount of gold to 500.

Comment: why would you give a companion gold?

Comment: @Skizzlefrits to make sure I don't spend it myself.

Comment: @DavidB doesn't sound like your companion is much better at saving. THIS IS WHY OUR ECONOMY IS RUINED.

Comment: @Skizzlefrits Because Inara is awesome. Wait. We *were* talking about **those** Companions, right?

Comment: @SamKrieg why didn't you just put it into a chest inside your house?

Comment: @SamKrieg, this is why you can't have nice things!!!

Answer (score 3):

For saving purposes, you're better off buying the cheapest house you can find and stashing your gold in a chest inside. Anything stored outside of your house (including on a body) will vanish over time as people "find" the item. Anything stored in your house is exempt from this vanishing act.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Why did the gold disappear?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I that has helped me is make sure you have stuff to sell before you go buy stuff. Buy what you want and then sell the stuff to make your money back. You may not get it all back, but you'll get most of it.

Overall, listen to what everyone else said and buy a house as soon as possible. It will make things so much easier. But keep it organized and don't forget you have to pay to furnish it.

Comment: Or just don't furnish it. There should be at least one chest and a few other assorted containers in any house when initially purchased.